# netty- how to transmit message and data together?

Tags: java, networking, netty

I mean like this:

In client side, a user input a file name, the client transmit the message of asking for the file to server, and server search for the file, if the file found, transmit a message to client for notification first, and then transmit the file's data to the client, if the file is not exist in server, just send back a notification message.

Since there are message and data in the transmission, how could I decoder them? Could anyone help me with that, if with some example code would be great help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using HTTP? You can use the HTTP status code for the notification, and the response content for the data.

There are plenty of Netty [HTTP example apps](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http).

Using HTTP may save you from having to invent your own protocol.